# How to implement a proper log out method in my flutter app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

```
_signOut() async {
    await firebaseAuth.signOut();}

            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              _signOut();
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage()));
            },
```

This is the way I implemented it in my code, but I have a problem when I want to register a new user after logging out from the current user. After I complete the registration form that I created, in my firebase it doesn't create a new user, but it just updates the former user info, like Name, Surname etc. To create a new user I need to restart the app.I think the problem is with the sign out procedure, I am not sure.

Comment: Use stream builder - e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322340/flutter-how-to-remove-bottom-navigation-with-navigation/52344225#52344225

Answer (score 0):

You should have a root page that would take the following.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  switch (_authStatus){
    case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
    return new LoginPage(auth: widget.auth, onSignedIn:_signedIn ,);
    case AuthStatus.signedIn:
    return new NifesHome(
      auth: widget.auth,
      onSignedOut: _signedOut,

    );
  }

}
```

what this does is if the user is signed out automatically he is taken to the root page which confirms the status of the user and redirects him to the login page.