# Add logic to flutter launch screen

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I'm using flutter, firebase and bloc pattern to create some app. I want to load user from firebase so if the user does not loaded yet I navigate user to login screen.

And now I have a lot of struggling with splash screens in flutter!
First of all I create my own splash screen with FutureBuilder and other stuffs but for some reason it didn't work correctly and It has some problem with navigator!

And now I found flutter launch screen and then I want to add some logic to it (like loading user, navigate to login screen and so on).

So is there anyway to add logic to this screen? (I changed my Main App class to stateful widget and tried to add some logic to initState function but there are some issues in it like I can not use Navigator in initState!)

Comment: i would suggest you to use StreamBuilder: - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52344225/10269042

Comment: The problem is I'm using `firebase_database` with `firebase_auth` and the state of user is not only dependent if he logged in with `firebase_auth`!

Comment: I mean, I can ONLY show my main screen IF the data has fetched from database NOT when user loaded